# Marketing tool to keep track of the states and results of various seeding posts

Tags: gratis, facebook, marketing

My main marketing platform is Facebook. In a campaign I need to keep track of the states (pending, accepted, rejected) and results (number of likes, hearts, comments, shares) of the various posts. If the data can be crawled automatically then it is great, but I can input them manually. Is there any such tools for that? I have decent programming skills as well. My budget is low, so I would like to have a free option.